# How do I get Maxima to store function output?

Tags: maxima

I have the logistic map function in Maxima like so:

```
F(x,r,n):= x[n]=r*x[n-1]*(1-x[n-1]);
```

And when I input the correct variables it gives me the answer to, for example, x[0]:

```
(%i15)  n:0$
x[n-1]:[0.1]$
F(x, r:3, n);
(%o15)  x[0]=[0.27]
```

However, this answer does not stay memorized and when I enter x[0] I get

```
    x[0];
(%o5)   x[0]
```

How do I write a function that will calculate x[n] for me and store it in memory, so I can use it later? I am trying to make a bifurcation diagram for the logistic map without using any black boxes, i.e., the orbits functions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to go about it. One straightforward way is to create a list and then iterate, computing its elements one by one. E.g.:

```
(%i4) x: makelist (0, 10);
(%o4)            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
(%i5) x[1]: 0.1;
(%o5)                          0.1
(%i6) r: 3;                       
(%o6)                           3
(%i7) for i:2 thru 10 do x[i]: r * x[i - 1] * (1 - x[i - 1]);
(%o7)                         done
(%i8) x; 
(%o8) [0.1, 0.2700000000000001, 0.5913000000000002, 
0.7249929299999999, 0.5981345443500454, 0.7211088336156269, 
0.603332651091411, 0.7179670896552621, 0.6074710434816448, 
0.7153499244388992]
```

Note that `:` is the assignment operator, not `=`.